# Why can I not include my cu-file header in my main.cpp file despite enabling CUDA in CMake?

Tags: c++, cmake, cuda, include-path, build-dependencies

I have a small c++ and cuda test project where I am trying to compile a simple setup containing a main.cpp file along with a test.cu and test.h file with some gpu functionality. My project setup looks like this:

```
project
│   CMakeLists.txt
│   main.cpp
|   test.h
|   test.cu
|
└───build
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24)
project(test LANGUAGES CXX CUDA)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CUDA_STANDARD 14)

set(SOURCES ${SOURCES}
  test.cu
)

add_executable(test main.cpp ${SOURCES})
set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES CUDA_ARCHITECTURE "75")
```

test.h

```
#ifndef TEST_H_ 
#define TEST_H_ 

#include <cuda_runtime.h>

void test(int *arr, int size);

#endif // TEST_H_
```

test.cu

```
#include <cuda_runtime.h>

#include "test.h"

__global__ void test_kernel(int *arr, int size) {
  arr[threadIdx.x] += 1;
}

void test(int *arr, int size) {
  int *temp;
  cudaMalloc(&temp, sizeof(int)*size);
  cudaMemcpy(temp, arr, sizeof(int)*size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

  test_kernel<<<1, 256>>>(temp, size);

  cudaMemcpy(arr, temp, sizeof(int)*size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  cudaFree(temp);
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

#include "test.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  int *arr = new int[10];
  test(arr, 10);

  delete[] arr;
  return 0;
}
```

I am creating the build files and compiling by doing

```
cd build
cmake ..
make
```

however, when running make I get the following error

```
In file included from /home/bickit/Documents/test/main.cpp:3:
/home/bickit/Documents/test/test.h:4:10: fatal error: cuda_runtime.h: No such file or directory
    4 | #include <cuda_runtime.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/test.dir/build.make:76: CMakeFiles/test.dir/main.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:83: CMakeFiles/test.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2
```

Why can I not compile my project like this when I have enabled CUDA as a language in my CMakeLists.txt?

My NVCC version is 11.7 and my cmake version is 3.24.1

Comment: In `CMakeLists.txt` add `set( CUDA_HOME "/usr/local/cuda")` and `find_package(CUDA QUIET REQUIRED)` or `include_directories( /usr/local/cuda/include )`

Answer (score 2):

You can definitely include your `test.h` header. The problem is that `test.h` includes, in turn, `<cuda_runtime_api.h>`; so the C++ compiler must have the directory containing this CUDA header - the CUDA distribution include directory - in its include path; and for that to happen, CMake must make sure and add that directory to the include path via the compiler's command-line.

Note that for the NVCC compiler, the CUDA include directory is automatically searched without requiring specifying it on the command line; and NVCC is what's used by default to compile the `test.cu` file - so you would not get the error message when including `test.h` in `test.cu`.

To have CMake add the appropriate include directory when compiling C++, do this:

```
find_package(CUDAToolkit REQUIRED)

# ... etc. 

target_link_libraries(test CUDA::cudart)
```

or directly add the relevant include directory with `target_include_directories()` (not recommended).